# Find all Function $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that $f(x+yf(x))=f(x)+xf(y) \; \forall \; x,y \in \mathbb R$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, functional-equations

> > Find all Function $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that $f(x+yf(x))=f(x)+xf(y) \; \forall \; x,y \in \mathbb R$

**My Approach:**

Let $P(x,y):f(x+yf(x))=f(x)+xf(y)$

Set $x=1,y=0$

$P(1,0): f(1)=f(1)+f(0)$

$\implies$

$f(0)=0$.

After this step i tried many combinations of $x$ and $y$. But I couldn't Find solution.

**$f(x)=0$ seems a obvious solution. I also tried $f(x)=x$ because many functional equation has solution $f(x)=x$ and that solution worked but I don't know how to prove this (i.e., $f(x)=x$) solution and any other solution which given equation can have.**

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3686113/42969 – found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f(x%2Byf(x))%3Df(x)%2Bxf(y)%24%2C%20AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Help needed with the functional equation $f \big(x + y f (x)\big) = f (x) + xf (y)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3686113/help-needed-with-the-functional-equation-f-bigx-y-f-x-big-f-x-xf). Also, the AoPS thread [Motivation behind HongKong 2004 FE](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1563273p9567915) has, in message #$3$, "Posted (and solved) many many times (2009, 2010, 2015,...)." &, after using the search function, that "You'll get in the ten first results (excluded your own post and this post itself) all the help you are requesting for".

Comment: Thanks, But why I didn't find above link. Why search engine didn't show me that?